# Ubuntu splash Screen is now a gear and boot speed is slow

Tags: 12.04, desktop-environments, plymouth, optimization

I installed lxde, gnome, and a whole bunch of other desktop environments the other day, and now while Ubuntu boots, the splash screen is now a gear on a gray background, and boot speeds have gone from a few seconds to two minutes.

Is there any way to change the boot screen back and increase the boot time?

Comment: Regarding the increase in boot time I doubt that it is caused by plymouth: probably you have more services starting up. You can use `bootchart` to identify what is slowing down startup.