# Cairo-dock and LXDE: Cairo-dock is always behind all of the Windows.

Tags: 12.04, lxde, cairo-dock

I have ubuntu installed, and I'm running it in the LXDE environment.

When I have Cairo-dock running, I have it set to 'Always on top', however, it sits behind all of the windows. I want the dock to autohide when it's not being moused over, and pop back up when I touch that side of the screen.

I seem to have figured that much out, however, it's always behind all of the windows I have open.

How would I fix this / configure it to work how I want it to?

Comment: Is [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/278996/25656) still true: *I installed lxde, gnome, and a whole bunch of other desktop environments the other day,...* ? If so, are you sure that nothing from the "whole bunch of other desktop environments" is somehow to blame? Or is this a computer with simply Ubuntu+LXDE?

Comment: This computer is just Ubuntu + LXDE. Everything else has been successfully purged. Should I have compiz running on top of LXDE?

Comment: Whether you want Compiz is entirely up to you. My personal preference is plain Lubuntu without anything for special effects. BTW, I don't use Cairo Dock. And haven't installed any other desktops on top of Lubuntu. So I can't even guess about what may be causing Cairo Dock to behave oddly.

Comment: Same here. I like plain LXDE, but a friend told me to try and install cairo-dock to see how I like it.